# How to set different color for upper and bottom area which is outside safe area in iPhone X

Tags: iphone, swift, safearealayoutguide

How to set a different color for the upper and bottom area which is an outside safe area in iPhone X i.e for point 1 and point 2 in the image?

If I set the color to main view (point 3) then it gets applied to the whole view. I want to set the different color to an upper area of the safe area, to a safe area and to below bottom safe area.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ut7A.png]

**add two views and give background color to them. if its not required in other view set hight 0 point of both view.**

Comment: Thanks for updates Vishal. The approach you suggested were will work for now. But I am looking for Apple's API to set it. if any?

Comment: i dont know if any API for that.